# Spring MVC Use AOP while 404 Error Occurred

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, aop

Now I have an aspect:

```
@Around(value = "execution(* package.controller.*.*View(..)) && args(.., request)")
public ModelAndView getUserProfile(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
    ModelAndView view = null;
    view = (ModelAndView) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    boolean isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn(session);
    if ( isLoggedIn ) {
        User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
        view.addObject("isLogin", isLoggedIn)
            .addObject("profile", user);
    }
    return view;
}
```

As you see, once the *View method was invoked, this aspect will add session information to the ModelAndView object.

However, when HTTP 404 error occurred, this aspect won't work.
But how can I add extra information to the ModelAndView object on 404 error page?

I have created my own error page for 404 error:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, rather an AOP expert. Can you please specify what "aspect won't work" means? Is the advice not triggered? Do you see an exception? Please add anything helpful to your question as an edit.

Comment: @kriegaex AOP works normally when the page exists(returns HTTP 200). But if the page not exists, there's no controller to handle the request. So the AOP won't work.

Comment: Why such a complex solution? Why not simply use a `HandlerIntereptor` or (in this case better) `Filter`. What is added to the model is simply exposed as request attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler` in your controller to handle errors and add extra information to the `ModelAndView`.  This will be invoked whenever there is an error and will let you modify the response.

Take a look at the Spring documentation located at: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Here is a good example that comes right from the Spring blog:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

```
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
  }
```